# Golang another unrecognized import path

Tags: go

When i am trying to install golint (or gin, for example) i get "unrecognized import path error".

I know that there are many same questions, but main answer is to check environment variables.

There is screenshot of my environment variables, my folders and console with error.
[image]

I tried to install go both with .msi installer and just by copying files and setting env var manually. I got the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [go get issue currently discussed](https://github.com/golang/lint/issues/158)

> my go tools were out of date, but go get could not update them because they switched form mercurial to git at some point. Deleting the whole golang.org/x/tools directory in my GOPATH and reinstalling fixed the issue.

Make sure you have the latest go, and try with a fresh empty `GOPATH` folder, to see if the issue persists.

Comment: No, reinstallation didn't fix it. Go 1.5.1, Git 2.6.1, Mercurial 3.5.2

Comment: @VitalySenko did you try with an empty GOPATH folder?

Comment: Add the most interesting thing is that i have all worked on my another machine, but i see no difference.

Comment: Yes. Both on clear and with bin,src,pkg created folders.

Comment: "Deleting the whole golang.org/x/tools " - i have no such directory installed. And trying do go get on this gcimporter fails too.

Comment: @VitalySenko Considering it is working without issue on my side, maybe there is an issue with your PATH? `echo %PATH%`. Try to have: `C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\prgs\go\go1.5.1.windows-amd64\bin;C:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.6.1-64-bit\bin;C:\prgs\hg\Mercurial-2.9.1-x64`

Comment: PATH is OK. I can do go/git/hg version in my console. I made exact Go setup on my notebook and all is OK. But my workstation fails. Main differences are: Notebook (Win 10, git 1.9); PC (Win 7, git 2.6)

Comment: @VitalySenko I meant: try with the smallest PATh possible, to make sure there is no side-effect from other programs in that PATH.

Comment: Can it depend on my hard disk ciphering?

Comment: @VitalySenko do you mean that your hard drive is encrypted? (as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption_theory)

Comment: Yes, you can see it in my explorer (in screenshot)

Comment: @VitalySenko That is possible indeed, I don't have direct experience with encrypted hard drive though.